# Synchronizing the result of threads with incremented shared variable and condition

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency

The title might not appear particularly clear, but the code explains itself:

```
int shared_variable;

int get_shared_variable() {
    int result;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&shared_variable_mutex);
    result = shared_variable;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_variable_mutex);

    return result;
}

void* thread_routine(void *arg) {
    while (get_shared_variable() < 5000) {
        printf();
        printf();
        sleep(2);

        int i = 0;
        while (pthread_mutex_trylock(&foo_mutexes[i]) != 0) {
            i++;

            pthread_mutex_lock(&foo_count_mutex);
            if (i == foo_count) {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&foo_count_mutex);
                sleep(1); // wait one second and retry
                i = 0;
            }

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&foo_count_mutex);
        }

        pthread_mutex_lock(&shared_variable_mutex);
        shared_variable += 10;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_variable_mutex);
    }

    return NULL; 
}
```

I'm passing `thread_routine` to a `pthread_create` (pretty standard), but I'm having a problem with the synchronization of the result. Basically, the problem is that the first thread checks the while condition, it passes, and then another thread checks it, it passes too. However, when the first thread finishes and `shared_variable` reaches 5000, the second thread has not yet finished and it adds up another 10 and the end result becomes 5010 (or `NUM_OF_THREADS` - 1 * 10 if I run more than two) at the end, while the whole process should end at 5000.

Another issue is that in `// do some work` I output something on the screen, so the whole thing inside the loop should pretty much work as a *transaction* in database terms. I can't seem to figure out how to solve this problem, but I suppose there's something simple that I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot release the mutex until the critical section is complete. Your critical section needs to include *both* reading and writing the variable and it needs to be done in a *single* critical section.

Comment: @kaylum, does that mean that the critical section should be the entire loop, and, considering that I have plenty of work in `// do some work`, wouldn't blocking the other threads for so long defeat the purpose of having them at all?

Comment: It depends how you want to arrange it. Generally in your case the loop body will be the CS. Not including the loop condition itself. But yes, if "some work" is long then there may be issues. But that is a performance issue and we are only talking about correctness in this question. If you want to discuss performance then you need to ask a new question showing exactly what "some work" does before others can explain how better to structure the threading.

Comment: The general principle is to make the CS as short as possible whilst still maintaining correctness. In your case you have made it short but not correct. But without knowing what "some work" is we cannot tell you whether some/all of it belongs in the CS or whether it can be excluded from the CS altogether.

Comment: I know the principle, this is why I feel bad for wrapping that huge amount of code. Anyway, I've edited the question with more detailed code. The `sleep()` calls are almost accurate simulation times of the real work.

Comment: You have added more code which is good. But it is not complete. In particular, we need to know exactly how `shared_variable` is used. The code shown only increments it. If that actually is the only operation on the variable (I guess it is not) then you could move the increment line up to the top of the loop and the mutex could be release early at that point. That's why we need the full code - cannot tell you how best to restructure without it.

Comment: It is the only operation on the variable, yes. The three usages of it are: reading it in the condition, increment in the bottom of the loop block, and then it is read once in the main thread - that's it. Could you please post an answer with the sample structure, because from what I understood I have the feeling that it would still be a problem (I guess that's what happens when you write multithreaded code for a day straight, haha)

Answer (score 0):

This answer may or may not be what you are after. Because as explained in the comments your description of the expected behaviour of the program is incomplete. Without the exact expected behaviour it is difficult to give a full answer. But since you ask, here is a possible structure of the program based on the code shown. The main principle it is illustrating is that the critical section for `shared_variable` needs to be both minimal and complete.

```
int shared_variable;

void* thread_routine(void *arg) 
{
    while (1) {

        pthread_mutex_lock(&shared_variable_mutex);
        if (shared_variable >= 5000) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_variable_mutex);
            break;
        }
        shared_variable += 10;  
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_variable_mutex);

        /* Other code that doesn't use shared_variable goes here */

    }

    return NULL; 
}
```